# Angular controller initialized every time its attribute changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller, angularjs-digest

I am building a one page application using angularjs 1 with ngRoute and I've come across a problem.

I have a view (/posts) using a controller (PostsController) that has an attribute called 'posts' which is an array containing all posts. Here's some code:

```
(function(){
  angular
    .module('thingy.posts.controllers')
    .controller('PostsController', PostsController);

  PostsController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function PostsController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.posts = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
      console.log("Hi...");

      test();

      // Simulates loading all posts from db
      function test() {
        vm.posts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Now if I comment test(), "Hi..." is printed once in the console. **However, when I uncomment it, "Hi..." is printed 1 + vm.posts.length times (7 in this example).**

Moreover, subsequent function calls also execute 1 + vm.posts.length times which is problematic.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Edit: Someone suggested the error might lie in my templates/routes **and he was right.** I am using a custom directive inside ng-repeat and when I remove it "Hi..." only appear once.

posts-index.html:

```
<div ng-repeat='post in vm.posts'>
    <post post="post"></post>
</div>
```

Post.directive.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('thingy.posts.directives')
    .directive('post', post);

  function post() {
    var directive = {
      controller: 'PostsController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        post: '='
      },
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/posts/post.html'
    };

    return directive;
  }
})();
```

Comment: your problem is not in the controller there must be  something else causing please share your templates and route declaration

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon You were right! My custom tag was using a controller, thus creating one every time... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in my directive declaration:

```
var directive = {
      controller: 'PostsController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
```

This was initializing a controller for every post on my page.